# Replacement for FBML fb:visible-to-connection

Tags: facebook, facebook-fbml

FBML [has been deprecated](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/). What's the simplest replacement for `fb:visible-to-connection`, which is used to show part a page only to fans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do in PHP (using the Facebook SDK). If you decode the `signed_request` data POSTed to your page, you can see if the user has liked the Page your app is on.

If you decode the data (e.g. in PHP you can do: `print_r( $facebook->getSignedRequest() );` to print the decoded version), you will see something like:

```
Array
(
    ...
    [page] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1234567890
            [liked] => 1
            [admin] => 1
        )
    [user] => Array
        (
            ...
        )
)
```

The `$response['page']['liked']` will be `1` if the user has liked the page, and `0` otherwise. You can then wrap your Fan Specific content around a conditional statement:

```
if ( $response['page']['liked'] === 1 ) {
    // user if fan
} else {
    // not a fan
}
```

Comment: No. The `$response['page']['liked']` will even work if the user has not used the app before, as long as they are viewing the app via a Facebook Page.